# SQL Server not writing date and time values to database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, batch-file, time

I currently have a Batch File and I am trying to get it to write the date, time and username to a SQL Server Database when run. Unfortunately the date and time are coming up blank in the SQL Server Database where as the username is being written to the database correctly.

The Batch File being run can be seen below:

```
<!-- :
Color 0A
@echo off
Set SearchDate = %Date%
Set UserSearchName = %UserName%
Set SearchTime = %Time%

sqlcmd -S LAPTOP\MSSQLSERVER02 -d AuditLog -E -Q " EXEC dbo.AuditLogCustomerIDTest4 '%SearchDate%', '%UserName%','%SearchTime%' "
```

The Sql Sub-Procedure which is being referenced from within the batch file (dbo.AuditLogCustomerIDTest4) can be seen below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AuditLogCustomerIDTest4
@SearchDate nvarchar (30) = Null,
@UserSearchName nvarchar (30) = Null,
@SearchTime nvarchar (30) = Null
AS
Insert Into UserSearches ([SearchDate],[UserSearchName],[SearchTime])
Values ((@SearchDate),(@UserSearchName),(@SearchTime));
```

The data types for each of the variables are:

```
1. UserSearchName(varchar(255),null)
2. SearchDate(varchar(255),null)
3. SearchTime(varchar(255),null)
```

Does anyone know as to why the date and time values are showing up blank within the SQL Server database? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `echo %Date%` etc to your batch file to confirm that you are passing in the parameters correctly?

Comment: Yes, i have done so and it gives the date in dd/mm/yyyy format. i.e. 09/02/2020

Comment: @DaveO123 Try Adding a date directly yourself (and compare it to the one you get from the script) this is most likely a formatting error

Comment: ```EXEC dbo.AuditLogCustomerIDTest4
@SearchDate = '01/12/2019',
@UserSearchName = 'John', @SearchTime = '10:32:39.67'``` - When this code is run from within SSMS the date and time are added correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup a table like yours and it didn't work either. UserName is making it into the table because you are using `%UserName%` instead of `%UserSearchName%`, so it's not using the variable you created. I turned on profiler and the values you are setting are not getting passed into the sproc. Because the variables don't have values. Get rid of the spaces before and after the equals sign and it should work.

```
<!-- :
Color 0A
@echo off
Set SearchDate=%Date%
Set UserSearchName=%UserName%
Set SearchTime=%Time%

sqlcmd -S LAPTOP\MSSQLSERVER02 -d AuditLog -E -Q " EXEC dbo.AuditLogCustomerIDTest4 '%SearchDate%', '%UserSearchName%','%SearchTime%' "
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. I would never have picked up on that